# how to catch when the connectivity is lost in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

i have the following script

```
rc=0
while [ $rc -ne 1 ]; do
 ping -c1 someip
   if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
      echo "lost ip"
   else
      sshpass -p password ssh user@ip 'date +"%s"'
      sshpass -p password ssh user@ip 'command1'
      sshpass -p password ssh user@ip 'command2'
     # some other commands
  fi
done
```

the problem is when ping lost connectivity when the script is executing the external commands through ssh, the script is hang even when the external machine recover its internet connectivity, so i was wondering how can i solve that situation.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/cause-a-script-to-execute-after-networking-has-started), and from the top answer, use [`systemd.special#network-online.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network-online.target).

Comment: you only show `rc=0` but no other code is shown that would change that value. This may, or may not affect your problem. Good luck.

Comment: If your connection to the remote host is that spotty, don't use three separate connections when one will do: `ssh user@ip 'date +"%s"; command1; command2'`.

Comment: thanks to all, the command that i was looking is timeout x seconds, cheers

Comment: Actually, you probably want `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=x`.